# how to console.log() longitudes and latitudes that are stored in mongoDB via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[i wants to fetch lng lat from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHv35.png)

**

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Map.find({}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(500, {
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.send(doc);
    doc.map((item,i)=>(
      console.log(item._id),
      console.log(JSON.stringify(item.data)),
      console.log(item.__v)
      ));

  });
});
```

**

But here i got the value of id and of __v and not of data items.I also tried without JSON.strigify(), but again fail.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center here and also [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).  This question contains far too little detail, shows no code that represents your effort so far, shows no indication that you've done any research on any parts of the question.  In addition, any data or code should be pasted directly into the question as text (and formatted appropriately), not linked as an image.

Comment: Brother please click on this link, you will understand easily from image

Comment: The way it works here is YOU have to create a question that follows the guidelines here and is clear and obvious in order to attract people to help you.  It's unclear to me what you're asking, even after clicking the link.  You can easily use the "edit" link to fix your question.

Comment: jfriend! i just wants to show lat and lng values in console.

Comment: If all you're asking is how to read the lat and long from that data structure, then why don't you just do what the guidelines say and say that in your question and paste the data structure into your question as text? Also, your question says something else about drawing a polygon in google maps which is far more than just displaying something in the console. I don't understand why you won't take a minute or so to edit your question to clarify it? Stackoverflow works because questions must be clear questions. And, filling in the details in the comments is not enough. Edit your question please.

Comment: check it now, i think it is at some extent better explain than before.

Comment: Better.  It is still against guidelines for information critical to understanding the question to only be available in an off-site link (your linked image).  This is because off-site resources tend to change over time or get deleted and then the question becomes useless as a long term reference to others.  That's why it would be best for you to include the data structure in text for in the question.  It also allows people to copy/paste it into answers.  I've made an exception and posted an answer.  Please understand the guidelines for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are correctly getting the value of the `._id` and `.__v` properties, but you want the `lng` and `lat`.  Those properties are buried inside of two nested arrays.

You have this:

```
doc.map((item,i)=>(
  console.log(item._id),
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(item.data)),
  console.log(item.__v)
));
```

which you say does get `item._id` and `item.__v` appropriately.  If that's the case, then you have to reach inside the `data` array.   For example, the first lng, lat you show in this screenshot:

[image]

would be:

```
doc.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item._id),
  console.log(item.__v)
  console.log(item.data[0].paths[0].lng);
  console.log(item.data[0].paths[0].lat);
});
```

To see all the values in those arrays, you would have to iterate both nested arrays.

```
doc.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item._id),
  console.log(item.__v)
  item.data.forEach(obj => {
      obj.paths.forEach(data => {
          console.log(data.lat, data.lng);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: console.log(item.data[0].paths[0].lng);
console.log(item.data[0].paths[0].lat);                                                                                  Brother the problem is that when i tried the above two lines, again i got the error     "
      throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined" i din nott know why i face this error and i already tried this technique.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama - Well, then show me what exactly `doc` points to.  You have a screen shot of some data that leaves me to try to GUESS what `doc` points to in that screenshot.  You said you were getting `item._id` and `item.__v` correctly in your code so I tried to guess what that meant `doc` is.  But, show me exactly what `doc` points to so I can help further.  I hope you can see now how your question is still NOT clear.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u5Xngt-obugS063vOIE-BZ9bmaN4TEUr/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                      now you can check the above link to see the output.And also thanks for your patience.I have no clarity in my question's description because i am a Student and newer on Stackoverflow. I hope, i will also learn these rules in a very short time.

Comment: @MuhammadUsama - I don't understand what that image is.  What does `doc` point at?  If you do `console.log(doc)`, what do you get?

Comment: `Conntected To Mongo Database
(node:15624) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
GET / 304 7ms
GET /javascripts/app.js 304 1ms
_id: 5e2c94b0a90b651e444eebe0
__v: 0
GET /maps 304 7ms`                                                                                                         [link]   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u5Xngt-obugS063vOIE-BZ9bmaN4TEUr/view?usp=sharing.                                                                     From the above output, you can see that, we only get two values (i)_id:--------    and (ii)__v: 0

Comment: @MuhammadUsama - What code generates that log?  I still don't know what `doc` points to.  You're not helping me understand that.  I'm going off to do other things now.  Maybe if you clarify someone else can help further.

Comment: if i do `console.log(doc)` i got   " _doc: { data: [Array], __v: 0, _id: 5e2c94b0a90b651e444eebe0 }," and here is the link of this result [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EX_ztyu0N1IVNR-R9ZQxE5DfcgvwJBvB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
      Map.find({"_id":'place_your_id_here'}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(500, {
            error: err
          });
        }
        res.send(doc);
        doc.map((item,i)=>(
          console.log(item._id),
          console.log(JSON.stringify(item.data)),
          console.log(item.__v)
          ));

      });
    });
```

**
you just need to enter the _id of the collection, that i was not mentioned here, and that was mine mistake, and now Alhamdullilah solved.